# ASP.NET MVC Persist Search Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view that displays some customer details in a list. The user can filter down the list using drop downs and text boxes to show results they are interested in and then JQuery/AJAX is used to return a partial view and update the list. For each item in the list there is an edit button which takes the user off to a different action to edit that specific item. When they save or cancel the user is directed back to the customer details page but the filters they had applied have obviously reset back to default. I was wondering what the standard way would be to tackle this seemingly common problem in the MVC world? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HTTP is stateless protocol , it's your responsibility to remember the state of the page. One of the way we do is show the additional detail on clicking the Edit button on the same page in popup . It will solve the problem in case you are ready to make the design change.

Otherwise you have to use the standard state management technique , like Session or Cache on the Server to remember previous search state or you can append some key value in the URL it self and when user cancel , recollect the state from the URL query string .

One more way if security is not concern is using the Cookie to store the previous selection on the client machine if it is very specific to user.

Comment: I cannot change the design of the page due to time issues so I'm stuck with what I have at the moment. I was thinking that sessions would be the way to go but I have many pages displaying different data, in a similar way to the example I describe above. If I have many different views and lots of users all storing their filters in session variables, are they any drawbacks to this?

Comment: Session do have a overhead because it will consume the web server resource , i think you can just have a look on the option of the Cookies which are sitting in the client side.

Comment: I've decided to store a simple Dictionary<string, object> in the session, set at the controller when the user filters down. When the page is reloaded I then check for existence of the dictionary session at the controller and pull out the values for the various filters, thus filtering down the data returned. This sounds about the best way of doing it ? I wouldn't have thought a dictionary would consume too much resource - it's also quite a small dictionary too, with only around 5/6 records ?

Comment: I agree for this much of amount it is best choice till the point it start growing to thousands users hitting at the same time so total size will multiplied by thousand

Comment: My application won't be used by many users at the same time at all so I feel okay with this method, it does however make me wonder how developers tackle this problem for enterprise applications where using the session would put a strain on resources and cookies may be out of the question too.

Comment: For this kind of cases they use the caching options like memcache or redis as there alternate way. As these system are fast as data are kept in memory + loosing the data is not that much mission critical

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Session` to persist their filters. It tends to be overused by inexperienced developers but the situation you describe is pretty much exactly what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to fake the update of current row.

Consider, You clicked a delete button to delete the row.
Now with jQuery-

```
$.get(url,data,function(data){
   if(data.success){
     $('row').fadeOut(300,function(){
     $(this).remove();  //<--- This is what I mean
   });
 }
```

});

Here you have removed the row on the basis of `Json` result and your page didn't need any refresh.

Also as in your case, Just load the edit `Partialview` at the same page by managing some space.
You can do this at least.